# mysql table name with '@'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

One of my database table columns have name like 'name@from'

how can i write select query for get all values for name@from columns

this query gave to me error

```
 SELECT `name@from` FROM tabName
```

Comment: I'd recommend [renaming the column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: If you can, at all, even consider changing the schema, then stop what you're doing, and immediately change the column to have a proper name.

Comment: It is not even possible to create a table like that: create table testing (name@value varchar(10)); yields ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@value varchar(10))' at line 1. I suggest u take the other's advise, rename your table if even possible.

Comment: @Churk: Wrap the column name in backticks (`)

Comment: Thats the first thing I attempted, and same error message

Comment: This is odd because [by the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html), `@` should be permissible inside backticks. (unless it is a disallowed filename character, but I don't think that's true, as I can create one on Linux)

Comment: can you show us what `show create table tableName`, i am not sure how you created a table with `@`

Comment: "this query gave to me error" .. what error?  That is very important to know.  Maybe it is a PHP error rather than a mysql error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `` around the column name :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "name@from" FROM tabName;
```

will do the trick

Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:

**ASCII**: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (*basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore*)

However, if the **ANSI_QUOTES** SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to quote identifiers with other characters.